# Should I color my background or keep it transparent?

Tags: print-design, transparency, print-production, digital-printing, paper

I'm creating a flyer and plan on printing on a metallic cardstock (Neenah Metallic in Chalice Silver to be exact).

My issue is that during the creation process, I used a background that was as close to the colored paper as possible, but I don't know if I should print without the background or keep it on?

Answer (score 2):

If you added a background color merely to mimic the color of stock, then remove the background before creating files for output.

If you don't remove the background, you will be covering the stock with ink and changing the appearance of the stock. If that's not your desired outcome, you **don't** want a background.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should also double check with your printer, but most likely background needs to be transparent for non-white paper stock.

Answer (score 1):

I would remove the background colour.

If it is there to simply give you and idea of it will look then there is no need for it. It would be a waste of ink, and also, it be shame to pay out for metallic stock to then cover it up.

Also, the artwork set up like this may not accurately show how the colours will appear. Obviously, I haven't seen your file, but a lot of softwares are not set to represent colour blending on stock by default.

So I would definitely try and have a few test print done to check the colour is represented how you intend it.